# definition of integration using limits

Tags: calculus

In almost all if not all textbooks it begins the definition of integration by $\lim_{a \to 0} \sum_{x=a}^{b} [f(x) A]$
When we come to integration it actually uses anti-derivatives and techniques of integration, why we can't use this definition? If we do , is there some kind of reference of summations that can be used in conjunction with integrating this way?

Comment: using the definition would be pretty difficult or lengthy in most cases, luckily, it was demonstrated that you can use the antiderivative, etc. Same reason you do not generally use the definition of derivative when calculating derivatives, but shortcuts

Comment: it's lengthy but is it possible

Comment: I didnt said it was not!

Answer (score 2):

It is too hard to integrate functions using the definition so for practical purposes we use antiderivatives. This method is based on fundamental theorem of calculus and Newton-Leibnitz formula as a part of this theorem:
$$\int^b_a f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

You can read more here about the theorem, formula and find proofs of them:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: it's hard but is it possible  ??

Comment: @Eng_boody Of course, why not? I can say that every time you use Newton-Leibnitz formula, you integrate by definition implicitly, as Newton-Leibnitz formula proof is based only on integral definition and basic calculus concepts.